# Multiple DB2 databases in one connectionstring to compare test tables to prod via ODBC

Tags: powershell, db2, db2-400

Like I can do in Microsoft Access, I would like to link to 2 IBM DB2 databases in one query statement.

The only way I can figure out how to do it is to link to the first database, extract to a datatable, then do a `ForEach-Object` and query the second database.

```
$iSeriesAccount = "USSRF_ADM"
$iSeriesDSN = "DB2_MR0P"
$Db2Connection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$Db2Connection.ConnectionString = "DSN=$iSeriesDSN;" +
                                  "Userid=$iSeriesAccount;" +
                                  "Password=$iSeriesPassword"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider Federation in one of the databases so that you can use a single query in that database and access tables from both databases

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/topics/tlsdb201.html

Comment: Thanks for the good idea but I have only ODBC access (and that grudgingly) and no ability to set up what looks like another server.

Comment: Despite the terminology in the manual you don't need to set up another server. You would just need run the `CREATE SERVER`, `CREATE USER MAPPING` statements, and then either `CREATE NICKNAME` or use three part names for the remote tables.  Oh, this was assuming you are using Db2 for LUW.  Looks like you are using Db2 for i

Comment: You should tag your question as `db2-400` hopefully someone with more knowledge of Db2 for i than me will chip in

Comment: I agree that federation is the way to go if the OP wants the processing to happen on the DBMS side. Otherwise they'll need to connect to each database individually, pull the data and do the comparision on the client side. Which is obviously not recomended for any non-trivial amount of data.